# How could I get this to display another row from the organisation table?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT s.staff_id, s.organisation_id, s.familyname, s.gender
 FROM staff s
 INNER JOIN organisations
 ON s.organisation_id = organisations.organisation_id;
```

**How could I get this to display another row from the organisation table?**

so far the results display the staff_id, organisation_id, family name and gender from the staff table and the organisation_id from the organisations table. How can i go from here to get the results to also display the organisation name from the organisation table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follow:

```
SELECT s.staff_id, s.organisation_id, s.familyname, s.gender,o.organization_name
 FROM staff s
 INNER JOIN organisations o
 ON s.organisation_id = organisations.organisation_id;
```

Here organization_name is the name of field you want to display from organisations  table.